# Invalid type passed to function at BaseController.js (line 430)

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I have been working with an Appcelerator project and stopped developing it for about a month. As far as I remember everything was running fine; however, now every time I try to run it I get an error "Invalid type passed to function at BaseController.js (line 430)". I really have no clue what that file is or does but its driving me nuts.

Below you can find the console log:

```
Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 26;
[ERROR] :      line = 430;
[ERROR] :      message = "Invalid type passed to function";
[ERROR] :      nativeLocation = "-[TiProxy addEventListener:] (TiProxy.m:837)";
[ERROR] :      nativeReason = "expected: Function, was: Number";
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Users/cilantrolabs03/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B6CA855E-CD76-45D1-88A7-931D2185F193/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2953E802-8E61-4398-A98F-CB168297EC0A/Uzy.app/alloy/controllers/BaseController.js";
[ERROR] :      stack = "[native code]\naddListener@file:///Users/cilantrolabs03/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B6CA855E-CD76-45D1-88A7-931D2185F193/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2953E802-8E61-4398-A98F-CB168297EC0A/Uzy.app/alloy/controllers/BaseController.js:430:26\nController@file:///Users/cilantrolabs03/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B6CA855E-CD76-45D1-88A7-931D2185F193/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2953E802-8E61-4398-A98F-CB168297EC0A/Uzy.app/alloy/controllers/index.js:55:59\ncreateController@file:///Users/cilantrolabs03/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B6CA855E-CD76-45D1-88A7-931D2185F193/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2953E802-8E61-4398-A98F-CB168297EC0A/Uzy.app/alloy.js:232:54\nglobal code@file:///Users/cilantrolabs03/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B6CA855E-CD76-45D1-88A7-931D2185F193/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2953E802-8E61-4398-A98F-CB168297EC0A/Uzy.app/app.js:18:23";
[ERROR] :  }
```

PS. Do you guys have any idea why the icon is being used as the splash screen?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide some code? And make sure that your eventListener callback function is not the same name as a variable and gets overwritten somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think your **BaseController.js** controller contains some event listener to an UI element.

Search this ***addListener*** in **BaseController.js** and see if you are adding any event listener somewhere and then you are passing the event listener a Number, not a function.